# is it better to keep the layout of the lists?

Tags: tables, lists, cards, infinite-scroll

I have an application that manages several entities, each entity has a list page, each entity can have a child entity with its own list page.
Are you using different types of lists? table, cards, infinite scroll, virtual-scroll
In general, does it make sense to keep the same type of list for the whole application or can you change the type of list?
and in the second case as a user I would not feel lost with different types of lists?

Comment: I think this is something that you should be asking your users. The answer will very much depend on your target audience and what they need to do with the data.

Comment: of course, but in general how would a user have 3 or 4 different list views?

Answer (score 0):

In general, keep behavior and interfaces [consistent](https://uxdesign.cc/design-principle-consistency-6b0cf7e7339f) to avoid users having to relearn and reorient every page they visit. It's hard to give a recommendation with no visuals or background info provided.